# Unable to deploy web application built with Spring Boot over Jboss 4.2.2

Tags: angularjs, spring, tomcat, jboss, spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot to build my AngularJS web application. Here is the pom.xml :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>supervision</groupId>
<artifactId>SUPERVISION</artifactId>
<version>0.1.0.RELEASE</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>SUPERVISION</name>
<description>SUPERVISION FRONT END + SERVLET</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> 
</parent>

<properties>
    <start-class>supervision.SupervisionServlet</start-class>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Both the servlet and the front end are working fine on Tomcat 8.0 but for some reason I have to deploy the application over Jboss 4.2.2. When I put my war file in the Jboss deploy folder, it returns me this warning and a 404 page not found:

```
WARN  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] Unable to process deployment descriptor for context '/SUPERVISION-0.1.0.RELEASE'
```

I have already tried to add server.servlet-path=/* in the application.properties file but it didn't fix my issue.

Any idea on how to fix this ?

Comment: Did you extend `SpringBootServletInitializer` as described here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file

Comment: Yes I did, I am now trying to add a web.xml file to my project, it seems that old servlet containers need one no matter if the project is built with spring boot or not.

Comment: @warzag Did you ever solve this?

Comment: @Josh nope sorry mate

Answer (score 0):

Since your not actually running on tomcat don't state that it is provided instead try excluding it.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Doesn't seems to work. Still have both 404 and warning.

Comment: hmm unfortunately I'm not sure then.  The packaging of the war file shouldn't need to change.  Might be something JBoss specific I'm not aware of.